# Running mysql database linked to my Django Project

Tags: mysql, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083408/fatal-error-cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-table-mysql-host-doesnt-ex)

I was watching the Python From Scratch ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRnm8f6Wavk ) and was trying to run mysql database to the django project and faced some problems

I typed mysqld to get mysql database running.

The error msg i faced is:

```
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
120604 12:02:05  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120604 12:02:06 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120604 12:02:06 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
120604 12:02:06 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
120604 12:02:06 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
120604 12:02:06 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
120604 12:02:06 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

Not sure how to solve this.. Need some help...

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at 3 days on the internet and everything I've seen did not work.
 Try this, see if in your mysql folder \data, you have the folder created by default, mysql and performance_schema floders.
 Normally if you delete these folders gives that error.

If you need those folders I suggest you install MySQL on another computer and copy these 2 folders in mysql / data, where you have your database.

Comment: I finally chose mysqlite cos it was much easier to get started with....