# Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I installed MySQL community server 5.7.10 using binary zip. I extracted the zip in `c:\mysql` and created the data folder in `c:\mysql\data`. I created the config file as `my.ini` and placed it in `c:\mysql` (root folder of extracted zip). Below is the content of the `my.ini` file

```
# set basedir to your installation path
basedir=C:\mysql
# set datadir to the location of your data directory
datadir=C:\mysql\data
```

I'm trying to start MySQL using `mysqld --console`, but the process is aborted with the below error.

```
2015-12-29T18:04:01.141930Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2015-12-29T18:04:01.141930Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083408/fatal-error-cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-table-mysql-host-doesnt-ex) might help..

Comment: Does anyone have a solution that will work for xampp? I'm having an error with mysql, something about a missing file called servers.MAI. The mod keep suggesting this question, but it's not working, shocker.

Answer (score 87):

You have to initialize the data directory by running the following command

**`mysqld --initialize`** [with random root password]

**`mysqld --initialize-insecure`** [with blank root password]

Comment: However, this is not an option for MySQL **5.6** and below. How would we deal with the error `Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist` then on such versions? What *exactly* is causing this issue and how can it be fixed without installation?

Comment: Found related threads: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/115701/9405 and http://superuser.com/q/660078/78897

Comment: to run `mysqld --initialize` open **terminal or command** prompt and move to `xampp/mysql/bin/` folder then run this command .

Comment: 1. before initialization make sure the data directory is empty. 2. random password is printed to data/HOST_NAME.err

Comment: What to do if mysqld has not `--initialize` and `--initialize-insecure` options? I got an error `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--initialize-insecure'`

Comment: Using mysqld --initialize-insecure created data directory and default tables for mysql which was not performed by WAMP during installation resulting in non start of MYSQLD

Answer (score 24):

The `mysql_install_db` script also needs the `datadir` parameter:

```
mysql_install_db --user=root --datadir=$db_datapath
```

On Maria DB you use the install script `mysql_install_db` to install and initialize. In my case I use an environment variable for the data path. Not only does `mysqld` need to know where the data is (specified via commandline), but so does the install script.

Comment: You would most likely use `--user=mysql` here to set the directory permissions to the mysql user that MariaDB runs as.

Comment: Updated command, for mysql-server 5.7 worked:
`mysqld --initialize --user=root --datadir=<datadir_location>`. Default <datadir_location> is `/var/lib/mysql`

Answer (score 5):

`mysqld --initialize` to initialize the data directory then `mysqld &`

If you had already launched `mysqld &` without `mysqld --initialize` you might have to delete all files in your data directory

You can also modify `/etc/my.cnf` to add a custom path to your data directory like this :

```
[mysqld]
...  
datadir=/path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, i had similar issue with *mysql-5.7.18*, I did this in this way:

1. Executed this command from `"MYSQL_HOME\bin\mysqld.exe --initialize-insecure"`
2. Then started `"MYSQL_HOME\bin\mysqld.exe"`
3. Connect workbench to this `localhost:3306` with username `'root'`
4. Then executed this query `"SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = 'root';`

password was also updated successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For some reason `--initialize` did not work. 
After about 5 hours of trial and error with different parameters, configs and commands I found out that the problem was caused by the file system.

I wanted to run a database on a large USB HDD drive. Drives larger than 2 TB are GPT partitioned! Here is a bug report with a solution:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28913

In short words: Add the following line to your my.ini:

```
innodb_flush_method=normal
```

I had this problem with mysql 5.7 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was caused by an incorrect db restore.
When I dumed the db it also picked up the system mysql tables because I added a space after `-p`  as mentioned here: [mysqldump is dumping undesired system tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488133/mysqldump-is-dumping-undesired-system-tables)

Launching the docker instance would work, then I'd restore (and corrupt) the db and it would still keep running, but after restarting it would Exit with error code 1.

The solution was to dump and restore properly without the system tables.

Comment: Thank you! I was facing exactly the same issue and this post helped me resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue with version `Mysql 5.7.33` when the server has rebooted. I fix it by copy other server user files `scp /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.* root@dest:/var/lib/mysql/mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues getting *MariaDB* up and running.

My system is Archlinux `Linux 6.7.4-arch1-1` and *MariaDB* *v10.5* but I built from source.  Having read over the "Post-Install" scripts I wanted to make sure that everything was setup as intended by the devs.

Specifically in, `scripts/mariadb-install-db`, which is typically invoked as root `mariadb-install-db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql` but if you're building from source (i.e. decompressing some binary or compiling) running the `mariadb-install-db` command will need the *either* `--basedir` *or* `--srcdir` *not both*.

For me, I ended up running `sudo mariadb-install-db --srcdir=. --datadir=/var/lib/mysql`.  Since I compiled from source I had to direct the install script to all the toolings and binaries.

For what its worth if going this route you will need to update your `PATH` as well.

I can see you're running a *Windows* based system but the above should be easily adjusted to for the difference.

```
# Create database directories
for dir in "$ldata"
do
  if test ! -d "$dir"
  then
    if ! `mkdir -p "$dir"`
    then
      echo "Fatal error Can't create database directory '$dir'"
      link_to_help
      exit 1
    fi
    chmod 700 "$dir"
  fi
  if test -n "$user"
  then
    if test -z "$group"
    then
      chown $user $dir
    else
      chown $user:$group $dir
    fi
    if test $? -ne 0
    then
      echo "Cannot change ownership of the database directories to the '$user'"
      echo "user.  Check that you have the necessary permissions and try again."
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
done
```

Where `$dir` is `--datadir` and `$user` `$group` are `mysql`.  You want to make sure that this directory is created and set with `0700` permissions (owner `rwx` is `0700`).

With this setup you can then run the daemon.  If you are still having issues there are steps to double-check from the `INSTALL-BINARY` file:

```
  41   │    The basic commands that you must execute to install and use a                                                     
  42   │    MariaDB binary distribution are:                                                                                  
  43   │                                                                                                                      
  44   │ shell> groupadd mysql                                                                                                
  45   │ shell> useradd -g mysql mysql                                                                                        
  46   │ shell> cd /usr/local                                                                                                 
  47   │ shell> gunzip < /path/to/mariadb-VERSION-OS.tar.gz | tar xvf -                                                       
  48   │ shell> ln -s full-path-to-mariadb-VERSION-OS mysql                                                                   
  49   │ shell> cd mysql                                                                                                      
  50   │ shell> chown -R mysql .                                                                                              
  51   │ shell> chgrp -R mysql .                                                                                              
  52   │ shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql                                                                         
  53   │ shell> chown -R root .                                                                                               
  54   │ shell> chown -R mysql data                                                                                           
  55   │ shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

There are very detailed instructions written up in the [source](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/11.4/Docs/INSTALL-BINARY)

Hope this helps!