# Why can't I start MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, archlinux

Arch Linux, standard kernel 5.16.3, MariaDB v10.6.5.

I try to start MariaDB, and it fails with

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

`systemctl status mariadb` gives me

```
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle mariadbd[2915]: 2022-01-28 20:13:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220128 20:13:13
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle mariadbd[2915]: 2022-01-28 20:13:13 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle mariadbd[2915]: 2022-01-28 20:13:13 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle mariadbd[2915]: 2022-01-28 20:13:13 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle mariadbd[2915]: 2022-01-28 20:13:13 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle mariadbd[2915]: 2022-01-28 20:13:13 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle mariadbd[2915]: Warning: Memory not freed: 280
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 28 20:13:13 gazelle systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.6.5 database server.
```

So okay, I can't connect because the server isn't starting up.  But even when it did start --- it did start on a few occasions, I would still get this error.  I looked in `/run/mysqld`, and `mysqld.sock` is there, with `777` permissions, and it's owned by the `mysql` user.  I've also made sure that `/var/lib/mysql` and everything underneath it is owned by `mysql`

Here's `/etc/my.cnf`

```
#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

[mysqld]
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[client]
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

#
# include *.cnf from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

What are the next possible steps?  I've scoured the 'net, and nothing seems to help.

Comment: Curious about the two missing tables causing errors. Did the install not go smoothly, maybe reinstall?

Comment: What does `ls -la /var/lib/mysql/mysql` show? What else is in the logs `journalctl -u mariadb.service -n 40`? Is this a new installation or an update from a previous version? Do you have package installation logs? Welcome to SO, please edit the question with added information.

Comment: Maybe you could start here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516664/cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-table-mysql-user-doesnt-exist/50497470

Comment: @David - The top answer there is mysql only and not mariadb. The second top answer `--user=root` shouldn't be used. I assume arch used `--user=mysql` for the permissions on files.

Comment: Seems like `Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '…' doesn't exist` are the relevant messages; just saying.

Comment: @PaulT. thanks for the comment. Helped clue me in to the issue. I thought it had gone fine, but I had forgotten a critical step.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so Paul T's comment

> Curious about the two missing tables causing errors. Did the install not go smoothly, maybe reinstall?

was the clue.  Looked at the [MariaDB page on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MariaDB#Installation), and I forgot to run `mariadb-install-db`. Should've RTFM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When initializing the database, `mysql_install_db` Whether the datadir directory is specified during dB. It is recommended to use `my.cnf` Specify the datadir directory in the CNF configuration file